# Camera app unable to write to app's internal storage

Tags: android, provider, android-11

I'm trying to capture camera image from my android app. Basically, I'm trying to achieve this by passing content uri (pointing to app internal storage) into camera app while launching it. But unfortunately, Below crash is occurring right after my app opens camera activity. Control is not coming into content provider so it is crashing even before control reaches my app. Camera app is crashing with below error.

Please let me know what i'm missing.
Content provider declaration in androidmanifest.xml

```
<provider
            android:name="a.b.c.provider.MediaStoreProvider"
            android:authorities="a.b.c.mediastore"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"/>

public static Uri generateMediaImageUri(long accountId) {

        String fileName = "";

        String uniqueKey = getUniqueKey();

        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = NAME_FORMATTER.format(new Date());
        fileName = String.format(IMAGE_PREFIX, accountId) + timeStamp + uniqueKey + IMAGE_SUFFIX;

        return Uri.parse("content://a.b.c.mediastore/image").buildUpon()
            .appendPath(Long.toString(accountId))
            .appendPath(fileName)
            .build();
    }


private Intent createCameraIntent() {
        mMediaImageUri = MediaStoreProvider.generateMediaImageUri(mAccount.mId);
        final Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaImageUri);

        return cameraIntent;
    }

2020-11-15 13:59:37.036 997-8747/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_topology
2020-11-15 13:59:37.036 997-8747/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_TOPOLOGY_ID
2020-11-15 13:59:37.036 997-8747/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> GET_AFE_TOPOLOGY_ID for adcd_id 513, Topology Id 10000ccc
2020-11-15 13:59:37.036 997-8747/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_afe_cal
2020-11-15 13:59:37.036 997-8747/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE
2020-11-15 13:59:37.036 997-8747/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE
2020-11-15 13:59:37.036 997-8747/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> AUDIO_SET_AFE_CAL
2020-11-15 13:59:37.036 997-8747/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> send_hw_delay : acdb_id = 513 path = 0
2020-11-15 13:59:37.036 997-8747/? D/ACDB-LOADER: ACDB -> ACDB_AVSYNC_INFO: ACDB_CMD_GET_DEVICE_PROPERTY
2020-11-15 13:59:37.036 997-8747/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: usecase(1) apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback speaker
2020-11-15 13:59:37.036 997-8747/? D/audio_route: Apply path: low-latency-playback speaker
2020-11-15 13:59:37.044 15188-15188/? W/CAM_CaptureActivity: Package a.b.c.droid doesn't have location permissions, location info won't be included in EXIF
2020-11-15 13:59:37.052 1015-1094/? I/VSC: @ 75988.802: {Fusion} configure fusion 11 200000us 0us.
2020-11-15 13:59:37.052 1015-1094/? D/VSC: @ 75988.802: [Rotation Vector Sensor] Request accel, interval 200.0 ms, latency 0.0 ms
2020-11-15 13:59:37.057 1015-1094/? D/VSC: @ 75988.803: [Rotation Vector Sensor] Request gyro, interval 5.0 ms, latency 0.0 ms
2020-11-15 13:59:37.057 1015-1094/? D/VSC: @ 75988.803: [Rotation Vector Sensor] Request mag, interval 20.0 ms, latency 0.0 ms
2020-11-15 13:59:37.057 1015-1094/? D/ASH: @ 75988.807: SensorType 1 resampler quality 1
**2020-11-15 13:59:37.085 15188-15188/? W/CAM_ActivityUiStartup: CameraActivityController failed!
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: GCA not granted write permission to content://a.b.c.mediastore/image/1/IMG_1_20201115_1359369962534309292671831.jpg, the specified output in intent: Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list {...}} (has extras) }.
        at oqb.b(PG:40)**
        at bes.a(PG:26)
        at ekq.<init>(PG:2)
        at ekr.a(PG:5)
        at elj.get(PG:5)
        at qjq.get(PG:3)
        at fnn.a(PG:3)
        at eeh.b(PG:362)
        at eeh.r(PG:149)
        at bjd.b(PG:6)
        at bjd.a(PG:9)
        at bso.run(Unknown Source:1)
        at bnw.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2020-11-15 13:59:37.085 15188-15215/? W/CAM_ActivityUiStartup: Interactivity failed!
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: GCA not granted write permission to content://a.b.c.mediastore/image/1/IMG_1_20201115_1359369962534309292671831.jpg, the specified output in intent: Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list {...}} (has extras) }.
        at oqb.b(PG:40)
        at bes.a(PG:26)
        at ekq.<init>(PG:2)
        at ekr.a(PG:5)
        at elj.get(PG:5)
        at qjq.get(PG:3)
        at fnn.a(PG:3)
        at eeh.b(PG:362)
        at eeh.r(PG:149)
        at bjd.b(PG:6)
        at bjd.a(PG:9)
        at bso.run(Unknown Source:1)
        at bnw.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2020-11-15 13:59:37.087 15188-15188/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-11-15 13:59:37.087 997-8747/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_write: retry previous failed cal level set
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-11-15 13:59:37.088 15188-15188/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.GoogleCamera, PID: 15188
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GCA not granted write permission to content://a.b.c.mediastore/image/1/IMG_1_20201115_1359369962534309292671831.jpg, the specified output in intent: Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list {...}} (has extras) }.
        at lrn.run(PG:2)
        at bnw.run(Unknown Source:6)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GCA not granted write permission to content://a.b.c.mediastore/image/1/IMG_1_20201115_1359369962534309292671831.jpg, the specified output in intent: Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list {...}} (has extras) }.
        at oqb.b(PG:40)
        at bes.a(PG:26)
        at ekq.<init>(PG:2)
        at ekr.a(PG:5)
        at elj.get(PG:5)
        at qjq.get(PG:3)
        at fnn.a(PG:3)
        at eeh.b(PG:362)
        at eeh.r(PG:149)
        at bjd.b(PG:6)
        at bjd.a(PG:9)
        at bso.run(Unknown Source:1)
        at bnw.run(Unknown Source:6) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
2020-11-15 13:59:37.088 1015-1094/? I/VSC: @ 75988.838: [DoubleTwist] doubleTwistPower 1
2020-11-15 13:59:37.088 1015-1094/? D/VSC: @ 75988.838: [Double Twist] Request motion_detect, interval 18446744027136.0 ms, latency 0.0 ms
2020-11-15 13:59:37.091 1551-6352/? D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 135634846; UID 10171; state: DISABLED
2020-11-15 13:59:37.092 1551-1665/? D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 143937733; UID 10171; state: ENABLED
2020-11-15 13:59:37.092 15188-15188/? W/CAM_ShotTracker: Uncaught exception. Annotating all active shots.
2020-11-15 13:59:37.096 1551-18970/? I/DropBoxManagerService: add tag=system_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2
2020-11-15 13:59:37.097 1551-6352/? W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity
2020-11-15 13:59:37.100 985-985/? D/Zygote: Forked child process 18971
2020-11-15 13:59:37.102 1551-15562/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.changepixelformat"
2020-11-15 13:59:37.108 1551-15562/? E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.egl.swapinterval"
2020-11-15 13:59:37.109 1551-15562/? E/FrameEvents: updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
2020-11-15 13:59:37.110 18971-18971/? E/ra:crash_repor: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
2020-11-15 13:59:37.100 1551-6352/? W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity
2020-11-15 13:59:37.112 1551-6352/? W/ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity a.b.c.droid/a.b.c.activity.MessageCompose
2020-11-15 13:59:37.114 1551-1664/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
2020-11-15 13:59:37.114 1551-1664/? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
2020-11-15 13:59:37.116 1551-1665/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 18971:com.google.android.GoogleCamera:crash_report/u0a171 for service {com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.google.android.apps.camera.app.silentfeedback.SilentFeedbackService}
2020-11-15 13:59:37.117 1551-1658/? D/EventSequenceValidator: Transition from ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED to ACTIVITY_CANCELLED
2020-11-15 13:59:37.120 15188-15188/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15188 SIG: 9
2020-11-15 13:59:37.129 1551-3633/? D/CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 136274596; UID 10171; state: ENABLED
2020-11-15 13:59:37.138 18971-18971/? I/ra:crash_repor: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-11-15 13:59:37.140 18971-18971/? D/nativeloader: classloader namespace configured for unbundled vendor apk. library_path=/data/app/~~1nPVuzYmg7wcx5L3dD4WiA==/com.google.android.GoogleCamera-Ahx8lap9A8BQ9s3M0bcP8g==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~1nPVuzYmg7wcx5L3dD4WiA==/com.google.android.GoogleCamera-Ahx8lap9A8BQ9s3M0bcP8g==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/vendor/lib64
2020-11-15 13:59:37.146 18971-18971/? W/ra:crash_repor: Insufficient pre-allocated space to mmap vdex.
2020-11-15 13:59:37.156 18971-18971/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-11-15 13:59:37.156 18971-18971/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-11-15 13:59:37.165 1228-1404/? D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0: bufferpool2 0x6ff97c7508 : 0(0 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 14/18 (recycle/alloc) - 4/17 (fetch/transfer)
2020-11-15 13:59:37.165 1228-2651/? D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0: bufferpool2 0x6ff97cc158 : 0(0 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 21/27 (recycle/alloc) - 6/26 (fetch/transfer)
2020-11-15 13:59:37.165 1228-1404/? D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0: Destruction - bufferpool2 0x6ff97c7508 cached: 0/0M, 0/0% in use; allocs: 18, 78% recycled; transfers: 17, 76% unfetched
2020-11-15 13:59:37.166 1228-2651/? D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0: Destruction - bufferpool2 0x6ff97cc158 cached: 0/0M, 0/0% in use; allocs: 27, 78% recycled; transfers: 26, 77% unfetched
2020-11-15 13:59:37.166 1228-2651/? D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0: bufferpool2 0x6ff97cd188 : 0(0 size) total buffers - 0(0 size) used buffers - 10/14 (recycle/alloc) - 4/13 (fetch/transfer)
2020-11-15 13:59:37.166 1228-2651/? D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0: Destruction - bufferpool2 0x6ff97cd188 cached: 0/0M, 0/0% in use; allocs: 14, 71% recycled; transfers: 13, 69% unfetched
2020-11-15 13:59:37.166 985-985/? I/Zygote: Process 15188 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
```

Comment: @blackapps I formatted the post.

Comment: `"a.b.c.provider.MediaStoreProvider"` You use your own provider? We have no idea why you would and what that provider does. So difficult to help.

Comment: `Control is not coming into content provider so it is crashing even before control reaches my app. ` If so, then post the code for the used intent.

Comment: @blackapps added code

Comment: We cannot see what is behind that uri from your provider. So we have no idea where data would be stored that the camera app wants to write. You also did not tell why you dont use FileProvider.

Comment: Further you could try to write to your uri yourself instead of sn external app.

Comment: We cannot see what you do with your camera intent. And it misses a flag grant read uri permission.